# Alternate option for scalar function in select statement of SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have a stored procedure to get the list of customers from my database. inside that SP, I have called the 2 scalar functions in the select query, which affects the performance terribly.

The scalar function has multiple if actions which check multiple cases and fetch the customer license information, so using this query in inline is more complex.

I know using the scalar function inside the select statement will call each time for a number of rows available.

my doubt is what is the best alternate way to avoid this performance impact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name we are using SQL server, I have updated the tag now.

Comment: Any suggestion anyone makes without seeing the actual code and tables structure can only be either extremely general or a wild guess. Therefor, I'm voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Part of the reason that the function slows your SP is that when creating the execution plan the internals of the function is not taken into consideration.
So first of all, making the code an inline one will improve performance. But i agree it can be very ugly and should be avoided.

You should probably pre prepare the data using a temp table but it's hard to say without seeing the code